# Generating filled contours instead having cloud of points with getdist utility

Tags: plot, statistics, contour, bayesian, mcmc

I ran a MCMC code and after convergence is reached (with automecee), I don't undertsand why I get a cloud of points (see figure in attachment) instead of having plain disk contours (see also other attachment). On some box, I get simply a full square , not really nice ellipse or contours expected.

The script using getdist is :

```
import os,sys
from getdist import plots, MCSamples
import getdist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Load MCMC samples
samps = np.loadtxt('./chain_BD.txt')


# samps 
samps = samps[:,0:7]
ndim = samps.shape[1]
names = ["x%s"%i for i in range(ndim)]
labels = ['\Omega_m', '\Omega_k', '\Omega_{BD}', 'H_0', '\Psi_0', '\dot{\Phi}_0', '\omega_{BD}']


samples = MCSamples(samples=samps,names = names, labels = labels)

# Triangle plot
g = plots.get_subplot_plotter()
g.triangle_plot([samples], filled=True)
g.export('./chains_final_BD.pdf')
```

**ATTACHMENTS** :

1. first case, the clouds of points

[image]

2. second case : filled contours :

[image]

It seems that I need an interpolation to transform the cloud of points into continuous filled contours.

Is there anyone already be faced to this issue?